# Meteor: How to catch asynchronous callback function errors

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, asynccallback

I'm trying to catch an error that could be thrown in an asynchronous function.

I have tried using the fibers package, but after the installation of this package, the app won't start giving this error:

> => Errors prevented startup:
>
> While building the application:
>
> node_modules/fibers/build.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

So I gave up on this package (this means also on the `Future` class)...

I also tried to wrap the callback function with `Meteor.wrapAsync`, but this doesn't do the trick either.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
try {
    Meteor.users.update({
        _id: this.user_id
    },{
        $set: {first_name: "test"}
    },{
        multi: false
    }, function(error, response){
        if(response < 1)
            throw "user could not be updated!";
    });

    console.log('user updated');
}
catch(error) {
    console.log('catched');
    console.error(error);
}
```

Since the callback function is asynchronous it won't be catched because the catch block code will already have run when the error is thrown. I'm just trying to figure out a way to catch the error I throw.

Comment: Is this on the client or server?

Comment: @user3374348 This is on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, `collection.update` can already be used synchronously. So all you need to do is:

```js
try {
  var documentsAffected = Meteor.users.update({
      _id: this.user_id
  },{
      $set: {first_name: "test"}
  },{
      multi: false
  });

  if (documentsAffected < 1) {
    throw new Error("user could not be updated!");
  }

  console.log("user updated");

} catch (error) {
  // will also catch exceptions thrown by Meteor.users.update
  console.log("caught an error!");
  console.error(error);
}
```